# Как передать id конкретного пользователя через сессию и получить id книги при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица reservation, где есть столбцы:     id, id_book,    id_reader,  bookissuingdate,    bookreturndate. Есть таблица book, со столбцами: id, id_section, Name, Author, BookEdition, Yearofpublication, Jenre. Таблица users, со столбцами: id, full_name, login, email, password.

Нужно, при нажатии на кнопку "Забронировать!" на странице book-1.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: /');
}


include_once("header.php");
 ?>


<?php
require_once 'BDconnect.php'; // Подключаем БД из файла

$image = 'book/'.$_GET['image']; // Получаем параметр GET, который передали

// table - название Вашей таблицы
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `image`=:image"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)

$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->bindValue(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Данные, которые передаёте в запрос
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Возвращаем значение.
?>


<table style="margin-right: 700px; margin-top: 20px;"  border='1' align="right" width="20%" cellpadding="28" cellspacing="0" > 

<?php
if (isset($_GET['res_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная
  $del_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['res_id']);
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM `book` WHERE `id` = '$res_id'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $dir='';
  unlink($dir.$row[0]);

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `reservation`(`id_book`,`id_reader`) VALUES ('{$_POST['id']}', '{$_POST['$_SESSION']}')");
    if ($sql) {
      echo "<h2>Данные о книге удалены.</h2>";
    } else {
      echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
    }
  }
?>

<form>
        <a href="#"><?= $_SESSION['user']['id'] ?></a>
    </form>


<?php
if($array) { // Выводим данные
 echo "<td>№ секции <td>{$array['id_section']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Название книги <td>{$array['Name']}</tr>";
 echo"<td>Автор <td>{$array['Author']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Издание <td>{$array['BookEdition']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Год публикации <td>{$array['Yearofpublication']}</tr>";
 echo"<td>Жанр <td>{$array['Jenre']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Количество страниц <td>{$array['NumberofPages']}</tr>";
 echo "<td><a href='?res_id=$id'>Забронировать!</a></tr>";
 echo '<img src=" Admin/'.$image.'"style=" margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 20px; width:400px;"; />';
}
?>
</table>

<?php
include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

получать id пользователя, который сейчас использует сайт и id книги, и записывать все это в таблицу reservation, в соответствующие поля.

BDconnect.php, если вдруг нужен:

```
<?php

try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=Library;host=localhost', 'Neko', 'qweqwe');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die($e->getMessage());
}
```

У меня не записывается ничего, id книги тоже не ищется, как и id пользователя. Но он выводит его на отдельную страницу. Мне не нужно,  чтобы меня перекидывало на другую страницу, нужно остаться на этой, просто после того, как пользователь нажал на кнопку 1 раз и забронировал книгу, чтобы при посл. нажатии выводилось сообщение, что книга уже забронирована.

Максимум чего я добилась, это вот этого:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: /');
}


include_once("header.php");
 ?>


<?php
require_once 'BDconnect.php'; // Подключаем БД из файла

$image = 'book/'.$_GET['image']; // Получаем параметр GET, который передали

// table - название Вашей таблицы
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `image`=:image"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)

$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->bindValue(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Данные, которые передаёте в запрос
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Возвращаем значение.
?>


<table style="margin-right: 700px; margin-top: 20px;"  border='1' align="right" width="20%" cellpadding="28" cellspacing="0" > 

<?php

$host = 'localhost';  // Хост, у нас все локально
$user = 'Neko';    // Имя созданного вами пользователя
$pass = 'qweqwe'; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
$db_name = 'Library';   // Имя базы данных
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой

// Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
if (!$link) {
  echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit;
}



   if (isset($_GET['res_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная
  $res_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['res_id']);
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM `book` WHERE `id` = '$res_id'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $dir='';

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `reservation`(`id_book`,`id_reader`) VALUES ('{$res_id}', '{$_SESSION}')");
    if ($sql) {
      echo "<h2>Данные о книге удалены.</h2>";
    } else {
      echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
    }
  }
?>

<form>
        <a href="#"><?= $_SESSION['user']['id'] ?></a>
    </form>


<?php
if($array) { // Выводим данные
 echo "<td>№ секции <td>{$array['id_section']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Название книги <td>{$array['Name']}</tr>";
 echo"<td>Автор <td>{$array['Author']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Издание <td>{$array['BookEdition']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Год публикации <td>{$array['Yearofpublication']}</tr>";
 echo"<td>Жанр <td>{$array['Jenre']}</tr>";
 echo "<td>Количество страниц <td>{$array['NumberofPages']}</tr>";
 echo "<td><a href='?res_id=$id'>Забронировать!</a></tr>";
 echo '<img src=" Admin/'.$image.'"style=" margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 20px; width:400px;"; />';
}
?>
</table>

<?php
include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Он выдает такие ошибки. Я не понимаю, почему он не видит добавляющих полей и что не так с таблицей reservation

[image: Вот скриншот ошибок..]

[image: Вот таблица. Я понимаю, какую ошибку он пишет, о чем она, но я не знаю, как ее исправить. Это нужно получается как-тополучить id пользователя через сессию, потом найти такой же в таблице и перенести уже оттуда?]

Comment: Я что-то не могу понять строк: $del_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['res_id']);
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM `book` WHERE `id` = '$res_id'"); Т.е. вы проверили данные из GET запроса и присвоили результат в переменную $del_id. А дальше в sql запросе вы пытаетесь подставить какую-то переменную $res_id, которая я не нашел даже где инициализировна.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы он остался именно на странице и она не перезагружалась? Или можно чтоб страница обновилась после нажатия на кнопку "Забронировать"?

Comment: вывод данных лучше переписать: if($array) { // Выводим данные...1.Нет открывающего тега table. 2. Нет открывающих тегов <tr>. 3. Сделайте получение данных из массива через foreach.4. Лучше не делать echo 7 раз подряд. Заведите переменную, например, $html = '' и конкатенируйте к ней строки ($html .= .... ). Затем выведите с помощью echo.

Comment: @Alik 46, можно сделать, чтоб она перезагружалась, я это имела ввиду~

Comment: Так, хорошо. idкниги он получает, записывает, с ним все ок. Но он потом отправляет куда-то не туда..  Не показывает ни картинки (она ломанная) ни данных о ней, хотя путь тот же, только вместо ссылки на картинку - переданный id книги. И он не передает номер сессии, точнее, id пользователя. Как это сделать?